# Possible to fade out an embedded Youtube video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api, jquery-effects

Is it possible to fade out a Javascript embedded Youtube video using Javascript/jQuery? At the moment I have embedded a video and when I try to fade it out using jQuery's `fadeOut()` function, it just disappears instead of fading. Is it possible to have a fade out effect on it using Javascript/jQuery or any other Javascript libraries (without any extra HTML elements)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `wmode = "transparent"`. See *[Create a transparent background in a Flash movie](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14201.html)*

**[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/uxobo4/7/)**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<object>
  <param name="movie" value="..."></param>
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>
  <embed class="video" src="..." type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
         wmode="transparent"></embed>
</object>
</div>
```

*Usage*

```
$("#wrapper").fadeOut(2000);
```

Comment: Why are you so lazy, lol? `$("#wrapper").hide().fadeIn(2000)`

Comment: I'm using SWFObject ATM to load the Flash and with that, fadeOut() works but fadeIn() doesn't...